# sbt unresolved dependency: scala parser combinators

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to use scala parser combinators in my scala project.
The only `.sbt` file I have in my project is **project/build.sbt**:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4"
```

I tried adding this line to **build/project.sbt**

```
    resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

but I get the exact same error.

When I execute `sbt`  from the terminal in the root directory of my project I obtain the following dependency error (those are the last lines before the error):

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.10;1.0.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.10:1.0.4 (/home/simonlbc/workspace/examslenstra/project/build.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]        +- default:examslenstra-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.10;1.0.4: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.10;1.0.4: not found
```

there are several lines which are it seems attempt from sbt to resolve the plugin at several different repositories:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.10;1.0.4
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/simonlbc/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /home/simonlbc/.activator/repository/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   /home/simonlbc/workspace/DB/DB2016/server/activator-dist-1.3.10/repository/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.10-1.0.4.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-releases-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugins-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== maven-central: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.10-1.0.4.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.10/1.0.4/scala-parser-combinators_2.10-1.0.4.pom
```

To write my **project/build.sbt** file I followed the directive given by the [github repository](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) of the scala parser combinators.

Of course when I do not specify anything in **project/build.sbt** I get compile time errors from sbt which does not understand where the Parser classes source files are.

Would there be any in which I could configure **project/build.sbt** so that I can use Scala's parser combinators library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this part of the error:

```
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.10:1.0.4 
                                                             ^
```

It looks like you're using Scala 2.10, where parser combinators are part of the standard library. They were split from the standard library as of Scala 2.11, so the jar you're looking for doesn't exist. If you're sticking with 2.10, simply remove that dependency, you'll get it in the standard library.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I deleted the build.sbt file. The compile time errors came from the fact that I forgot to import the classes and traits of the scala.util.parsing.combinator package.